# Issue with astropy conesearch in the SDSS DR8 for specific object

Tags: python, astronomy, astropy

I need to search this specific catalog for objects near this coordinate. I am trying to code it because not only do I have this object, but I have many others.

Seting it up:

```
>>> from astropy.vo.client import conesearch
>>> from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord
>>> from astropy import units as u
>>> db = 'SDSS DR8 - Sloan Digital Sky Survey Data Release 8 2'
>>> search_size = 1*u.deg
>>> c = SkyCoord(ra = 305.008942, dec = -0.975747, unit=u.deg)
```

Running it:

```
>>> conesearch.conesearch(c, search_size, catalog_db=db)
Trying http://wfaudata.roe.ac.uk/sdssdr8-dsa/DirectCone?DSACAT=SDSS_DR8&DSATAB=SpecObjAll&
Downloading http://wfaudata.roe.ac.uk/sdssdr8-dsa/DirectCone?DSACAT=SDSS_DR8&DSATAB=SpeDownloading http://wfaudata.roe.ac.uk/sdssdr8-dsa/DirectCone?DSACAT=SDSS_DR8&DSATAB=SpecObjAll&SR=1.0&DEC=-0.975747&RA=305.008942&VERB=1 [Done]
WARNING: W50: http://wfaudata.roe.ac.uk/sdssdr8-dsa/DirectCone?DSACAT=SDSS_DR8&DSATAB=SpecObjAll&SR=1.0&DEC=-0.975747&RA=305.008942&VERB=1:51:0: W50: Invalid unit string 'days' [astropy.io.votable.exceptions]
WARNING: W50: http://wfaudata.roe.ac.uk/sdssdr8-dsa/DirectCone?DSACAT=SDSS_DR8&DSATAB=SpecObjAll&SR=1.0&DEC=-0.975747&RA=305.008942&VERB=1:237:0: W50: Invalid unit string 'Angstroms' [astropy.io.votable.exceptions]
WARNING: W50: http://wfaudata.roe.ac.uk/sdssdr8-dsa/DirectCone?DSACAT=SDSS_DR8&DSATAB=SpecObjAll&SR=1.0&DEC=-0.975747&RA=305.008942&VERB=1:240:0: W50: Invalid unit string 'Angstroms' [astropy.io.votable.exceptions]
WARNING: W50: http://wfaudata.roe.ac.uk/sdssdr8-dsa/DirectCone?DSACAT=SDSS_DR8&DSATAB=SpecObjAll&SR=1.0&DEC=-0.975747&RA=305.008942&VERB=1:345:0: W50: Invalid unit string 'nanomaggies' [astropy.io.votable.exceptions]
WARNING: W50: http://wfaudata.roe.ac.uk/sdssdr8-dsa/DirectCone?DSACAT=SDSS_DR8&DSATAB=SpecObjAll&SR=1.0&DEC=-0.975747&RA=305.008942&VERB=1:348:0: W50: Invalid unit string 'nanomaggies' [astropy.io.votable.exceptions]
WARNING: W50: http://wfaudata.roe.ac.uk/sdssdr8-dsa/DirectCone?DSACAT=SDSS_DR8&DSATAB=SpecObjAll&SR=1.0&DEC=-0.975747&RA=305.008942&VERB=1:351:0: W50: Invalid unit string 'nanomaggies' [astropy.io.votable.exceptions]
WARNING: W50: http://wfaudata.roe.ac.uk/sdssdr8-dsa/DirectCone?DSACAT=SDSS_DR8&DSATAB=SpecObjAll&SR=1.0&DEC=-0.975747&RA=305.008942&VERB=1:354:0: W50: Invalid unit string 'nanomaggies' [astropy.io.votable.exceptions]
WARNING: W50: http://wfaudata.roe.ac.uk/sdssdr8-dsa/DirectCone?DSACAT=SDSS_DR8&DSATAB=SpecObjAll&SR=1.0&DEC=-0.975747&RA=305.008942&VERB=1:357:0: W50: Invalid unit string 'nanomaggies' [astropy.io.votable.exceptions]
WARNING: W50: http://wfaudata.roe.ac.uk/sdssdr8-dsa/DirectCone?DSACAT=SDSS_DR8&DSATAB=SpecObjAll&SR=1.0&DEC=-0.975747&RA=305.008942&VERB=1:360:0: W50: Invalid unit string 'nanomaggies' [astropy.io.votable.exceptions]
WARNING: W50: http://wfaudata.roe.ac.uk/sdssdr8-dsa/DirectCone?DSACAT=SDSS_DR8&DSATAB=SpecObjAll&SR=1.0&DEC=-0.975747&RA=305.008942&VERB=1:363:0: W50: Invalid unit string 'nanomaggies' (suppressing further warnings of this type...) [astropy.io.votable.exceptions]
WARNING: W06: http://wfaudata.roe.ac.uk/sdssdr8-dsa/DirectCone?DSACAT=SDSS_DR8&DSATAB=SpecObjAll&SR=1.0&DEC=-0.975747&RA=305.008942&VERB=1:462:0: W06: Invalid UCD 'IMAGE?': UCD has invalid character '?' in 'IMAGE?' [astropy.io.votable.exceptions]
WARNING: W25: ?:?:?: W25: 'http://wfaudata.roe.ac.uk/sdssdr8-dsa/DirectCone?DSACAT=SDSS_DR8&DSATAB=SpecObjAll&' failed with: Catalog server 'http://wfaudata.roe.ac.uk/sdssdr8-dsa/DirectCone?DSACAT=SDSS_DR8&DSATAB=SpecObjAll&' returned 0 result [astropy.io.votable.exceptions]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/astropy/vo/client/conesearch.py", line 191, in conesearch
    kwargs=args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/astropy/vo/client/vos_catalog.py", line 877, in call_vo_service
    raise VOSError(err_msg)
astropy.vo.client.exceptions.VOSError: None of the available catalogs returned valid results.
```

I know that the WARNINGS are just odd issues with the way SDSS set up their search, and it should not effect anything. I have tried up to 20 degrees and still can't find anything. This is just wrong, because I have other objects that are with in 20 degrees and they find objects!

Comment: It could just be a temporary issue with the catalog server, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Iguananaut, I ran it on a larger list, and about 80% work. Do you think the server would have issues like that?